# Material-UI: Disable only the action icon for Chip

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to disable the (x) for chip. not the entire component, trying setting up the disabled will disable the entire component.

[image]

How can I do that ?

Based on Paven answer I've tried

```
import Chip from '@material-ui/core/Chip';
import CancelIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Cancel';
import FaceIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Face';

{agent.assignedBots.map(assignedBot => {
   return (
     <Chip
       key={assignedBot.id}
       icon={<FaceIcon />}
       label={assignedBot.name}
       onDelete={() =>
          onRemoveBotHandler(agent.id, assignedBot.id)
       }
       color="secondary"
       deleteIcon={
       <CancelIcon
         disabled={
          (state.removedBot.id == assignedBot.id &&
            state.removedBot.disabled) ||
          assignedBot.isRunning
          }
        />
       }
    />
  );
})}
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CancelIcon` is just a svg element, it doesn't have `disabled` props. If you want to disable it, wrap the icon inside `IconButton` and set `disabled` to true:

```js
<Chip
  onDelete={handleDelete}
  deleteIcon={
    <IconButton disabled>
      <CancelIcon />
    </IconButton>
  }
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66999737/material-ui-disable-only-the-action-icon-for-chip]

Answer (score 1):

In this `Chip` component delete icon (x) is rendered by default when you have `onDelete` set. So if you want to really control the delete icon then you need to override this icon property.

[As per official doc](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/), `deleteIcon property on the chip component will override the default delete icon element. Shown only if onDelete is set.`

So you would want to try something like this, here `<DeleteIcon> is the actual delete icon that you want to show, you can replace with any icon you want`

`deleteIcon={<DeleteIcon disabled={disableDelete}/>}` by adding this you ll have more control deleteIcon, you can use disabled or any suitable property in your control.

```
<Chip
        size="small"
        icon={<FaceIcon />}
        label="Deletable Secondary"
        onDelete={handleDelete}
        color="secondary"
        deleteIcon={<DeleteIcon disabled={disableDelete}/>}
      />
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but I could not make it to work. I've updated my question so that it includes the piece of code tried. Can you spot anything that I migh be missing ?

Comment: @boris it doesn't work because `DeleteIcon` is an icon element which doesn't really have `disabled` props

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Somehow I missed it.